# How to separate a dataset into more than 2 random samples

Tags: python, random, scikit-learn, sampling, resampling

If I have a dataset with say 1000 rows, what is the best way to separate the dataset into say 5 random samples (ie. each sample will have 200 rows).

I know there are functions like `model_selection.train_test_split()` and `utils.resample()` but these functions only separate the dataset into 2 samples.

Do I first need to generate a list of random numbers, in this case a list of 1000 random numbers (say from 1 to 1000), and then take the index in the dataset corresponding to having numbers 1 to 200 as the first random sample, 201 to 400 as the second random sample, 401 to 600 as the third random sample etc.

Or is there a function in Python somewhere that I could use (to make my life easier)?

Comment: `scikit-learn.model_selection.KFold` ought to do it... https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html (or look at stratified kfold if you have a big class imbalance)

Comment: Do you have *labels* in your dataset, according to which you may need to stratify your subsets, or just a random splitting will do?

Comment: Thanks @Andrew but `scikit-learn.model_selection.KFold` or stratified kfold gives folds, not **non-overlapping samples** which is what I am after.

Comment: `KFold` can easily do that - what about my question above? And what is the *form* of your data? pandas dataframe? Other?

Comment: Hi @desertnaut, yeah my dataset has labels, so if there is a function which can also do stratified sampling would help. The data can be dataframe or arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Kfold` from `scikit-learn` to generate the indices you're asking for. If you take the smaller fold (the 20 %) then you'll have the 5 slices of data you need:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
import numpy as np

data = range(10)
kf = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True)
for i in kf.split(data):
    print(i[1])
```

Here are your pseudo-random, non-overlapping indices for you to select the relevant portions of your data/labels

```
[4 9]
[1 3]
[6 7]
[0 2]
[5 8]
```

If you wanted Stratified sampling, then you will have to use StratifiedKFold in a similar way.

If you want it as a function, I would probably create it as a generator:

```
def segment_data(data, labels, no_segments=5, shuffle=True):
    kf = KFold(n_splits=no_segments, shuffle=shuffle)
    for _, indices in kf.split(range(data.shape[0])):
        yield data[indices], labels[indices]

my_labels = ["L1", "L2", "L3"]
all_labels = np.random.choice(my_labels, size=100, replace=True, p=(0.1, 0.45, 0.45)
all_data = np.random.uniform(size=100)

for data, labels in segment_data(all_data, all_labels):
    print(data)
    print(labels)
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrew for this. Do you know if there is a function/package in a Python library somewhere which could split up my dataset automatically without having to manually create the indexes and then having to use the indexes to split the dataset? It would really make my life much easier.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything that can do that, I would probably just stick the above into a function myself if I needed to do it a lot